# PopAsync not working when i use it in a TabbedPage ViewModels

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Ok so in my previous design, on my MainPage which is called TasksGroupPage, i had a "+" icon that was taking me to a NewTasksGroupPage to fill a form and then click the save command to create a new TasksGroup ( so i don't need the + icon function to load the page anymore).

This was working perfectly and after clicking the save button it would take me to the MainPage.

But my problem is that i changed my design, i now removed the + icon and instead i created a new tab which now takes me to the NewTasksGroupPage.

To create this tab i simply added to my TasksGroupPage( the main page) the following code : `<views:NewTasksGroupPage></views:NewTasksGroupPage>`

**The problem now is that :**
When i click the save command in my NewTaskPageViewModel , the page doesn't  take me to the last page like it did before ALSO it's leaving all the text in the entry box there and it only create my TasksGroupPage after a while.

How should i set up this new design to work properly ? If impossible to do, is there a way to add a GestureRecognizers to one of the tab ?

Thanks.

Here you can see my code right now :

**TasksGroupPage.xaml**

```
<TabbedPage>
    <ContentPage>
    // some xaml
    </contentPage>
<views:NewTasksGroupPage></views:NewTasksGroupPage>

</TabbedPage>
```

**TasksGroupPage.xaml.cs this is the function that i don't need anymore but this is what i was using with the + icon**

```
protected async void GoToNewTaskPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.NewTasksGroupPage());
}
```

**NewTaskPageViewModel.cs this is the end of my save command which before took me to the main page ( TasksGroupPage) but now it just stays there and doesn't reset my entries to blank ( even when switching between other tabbed pages)**

```
    async Task SaveNewTask()
    {
    //some code
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
    
    }
```

Comment: you are trying to force a tabbed UI to do something that it is really not intended for

Comment: @Jason So it's impossible ? Is there a way that i could add a GestureRecognizers to one of the tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [document Xamarin.Forms Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/):

You will find that NavigationPage and TabbedPage are two different ways to navigate pages in Xamarin.forms.

`Navigation.PushAsync` and `Navigation.PopAsync` only works in NavigationPage, it does not work in TabbedPage, that's why `the page doesn't take me to the last page like it did before`.

If you use a TabbedPage, you can use below code to switch page:

```
async void SaveNewTask(object sender, EventArgs args)
{

    //this here means the current ContentPage 
    //this.Parent = NavigationPage
    var tabbedPage = this.Parent.Parent as TabbedPage;

    //if you don't have navigationPage, just use:
    //var tabbedPage = this.Parent as TabbedPage;

    //Switch to first page in tabs
    tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, currently since my SaveNewTask method is in a ViewModels, i think it's impossible for me to get the Parent keyword ( it's not recognized). Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: For more info : my app starts in TasksGroupPage which is the only page with the TabbedPage attribute, then when i click on the + tab, it takes me to NewTasksGroupPage which is a ContentPage that is linked with NewTaskPageViewModel which has the save command ( i think the way you did it is from the xaml.cs file)

Comment: Can you please share us [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? If you can't achieve that in VM, how about using MessagingCenter in VM to notify the Page to back to the previous page.