# PopAsync() to remove the current Content Page?

Tags: maui

I have a ContentPage within a tabbedpage.  I open another content page with a standard

```
Navigation.PushAsync(navpage);
```

Everything opens properly and my listview displays data.  When I select an item in my listview, I want to send a message out, and then close the current listview.  I do the following.  Unfortunately, my current content page doesn't do anything.  In the code below, I am trying this by forcing it on the main ui thread.  I have also tried this without doing this on a "BeginInvokeOnMainThread()" call, but that doesn't do anything either.  FYI, I have also tried this on the Displatcher.DispatchAsync() method call as well.  Any suggestions on how to get the current contentpage to close are appreciated.

```
private async void cvTags_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    var item = (CommonTag)(e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault());
    var tag = String.Empty;
    if (item != null) {
        tag = item.name;

    }
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send<string>(tag);
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        _ = Navigation.PopAsync();
    });
}
```

TIA

Comment: TabbedPage and NavigationPage are two different ways to navigate pages. If you want to use Navigation, you may wrap the ContentPage with in a NavigationPage object. See [Navigate within a tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-8.0#navigate-within-a-tab). Also, this answer might help, [PopAsync not working when i use it in a TabbedPage ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62881819/popasync-not-working-when-i-use-it-in-a-tabbedpage-viewmodels).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Navigation.RemovePage` to remove the current page.

First, you need to create an element to click.

Then, you need to put the code below in the method.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      Navigation.RemovePage(this);

}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, calling remove page is causing an error: 'Cannot remove root page when it is also the currently displayed page.'

Comment: I ended up just sending a message to my tab controller and my tab controller then reloaded a new item on the tabbar.  Strange, but it worked.

Comment: This might be a workaround for this issue. Good job.